# With vs Identify Block in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me (using some simple examples), the difference between the with{} and identify{} blocks in Groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there isn't one, they do the same thing.  From the [Groovy docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#identity%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

`identity`

```
Allows the closure to be called for the object reference self. 
Synonym for 'with()'.
```